# Is threshold crossing height and glide path angle the same for ALL airports and applied to ALL aircraft?

Tags: airport, flight-controls

It seems to be agreed (at an international level) that these values are standard and should be respectively 50 ft and 3 degrees. Are all airports following these rules, and are they applied to all type of aircraft?

Why would departure operations not have the same kind of constraints?

Comment: The short answer is "no", especially for TCH.  (Long answer will come later today if nobody else gets it :)

Comment: LCY (London City) has an approach that is 5.5 degrees, and it used to be 7.5 degrees at one point in the past. I also know some short-field approaches if you are 50' over the threshold when crossing it, you are going to end up in the bushes at the end of the runway.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject, I will accept Gerry's answer, but your input is more than welcome! :)

Comment: @harveyAJ -- I'd just have restated what Gerry said

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the US, the requirements are specified in FAA [Order 8260.3](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8260.3C.pdf), United States Standard for Terminal Instrument Procedures (TERPS).

Section 2-3 states:

> 2-3. General PA Requirements. See Order 8260.19 for requirements
>   related to GPA/TCH coincidence.
>   a. GPA. Utilize a standard 3-degree 
>   GPA where possible. GPAs greater than 3 degrees but not more than the
>   maximum (table 2-1) are authorized without approval when needed to
>   provide obstacle clearance or to meet simultaneous parallel approach
>   standards. Other cases or GPAs less than 3 degrees require Flight
>   Standards or military authority approval (USAF not applicable).
>                      [image]
>
> b. TCH. The published TCH (nearest whole foot) should accommodate the
>   largest aircraft height group normally expected to use the runway and
>   must not be less than the minimum or exceed the maximum TCH.   Note:
>   60 feet is the maximum TCH regardless of height group.
>   (1) CAT I.
>   The TCH is based on achieving an acceptable wheel crossing height
>   (WCH). The WCH is the difference between the TCH and the approximate
>   glidepath antenna-to-wheel height (see table 2-2).
>   (a) The optimum
>   TCH provides a 30-foot WCH. It must provide a WCH no less than 20 feet
>   or greater than 50 feet.
>   (b) Displaced Threshold Considerations. The
>   TCH over a displaced threshold can result in a WCH of not less than 10
>   feet if the height of the glide path over the beginning of the full
>   strength runway pavement suitable for landing falls within the
>   minimum/maximum TCH values.
>   (2) CAT II/III. The optimum TCH is 55
>   feet and must be between 50 and 60 feet regardless of height group.
>
> [image]    Note: To determine the
>   minimum allowable TCH, add 20 feet to the glidepath-to-wheel height
>   and to determine the maximum allowable TCH, add 50 feet to the
>   glidepath-to-wheel height (not to exceed 60 feet).

So, the answer to the question is ; No, they are not all 3 degrees and 50 feet.

Comment: Additionally, many/most approaches do not match the 3.00 and 50 "rule" in actual practice.

Comment: Incredibly useful! Thanks A LOT for your input. @JonathanWalters what kind of tolerance is acceptable. are we talking +/- 10%, or more? Table 2.1 shows, for category A a max GPA of 6.4 -- which means that you literally double the touch down distance. Surprising.

Answer (score 0):

It almost depends on the airport location(e.g. mountain area, city), in USSR most GTA were 2.40 degrees, and for military in ex-USSR countries they are still 2.40 dergees, because they use another ground facilities.